# How do I replace a certain amount of zeros in a string with an amount that the user is asked to input, starting from the end of the string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to coding and im learning python and I have a certain problem.
I'm writing a program which requires the user to input an amount and I want the program to always
print out 15 zeros but I want the amount the user inputs to replace the zeros starting from the end.
For example, if the user enters `43525`.
The program would print `000000000043525`

Also for example if the user inputs `2570.20`
The program would print `000000000257020` (removes dot automatically)

can anyone help me with how I should go about doing this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm really new so I have no idea where I should start other than creating a list with 15 zeros.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.replace()` to remove any decimal point and `.rjust()` to add the right number of zeros

```py
print(input('number: ').replace('.', '').rjust(15, '0'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use simple string manipulations to do this. For example:

```
k = 212.12

if '.' in str(k):
    string = str(k).replace('.','')
    print('0'*(15-len(string))+string)

else:
    print('0'*(15-len(str(k)))+str(k))
```

Comment: That will lose trailing zeros, which the OP says they want to retain (see the `2570.20` example). However, if the input values are strings rather than integers/floats, it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using list slicing

added_string = added_string.replace(".", "")
new_str = start_string[:len(start_string) - len(added_str)] + added_string

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zfill` for this:

```
print(''.join(input('Enter number: ').split('.')).zfill(15))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add leading 0s by using this string formatting while printing:

```
print("%015d" % (int(number),))
```

This means 0s will be added until 15 characters are printed.
For the removal of decimal dot you can use string replace method:

```
number = str(number).replace('.', '')
```

This should get you started.